# elseif echo issue, prints wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem i cant figure out. 
From my point of view, this should actually work...
The database is setup with 3 different priority values.
0,1,2 where 0=LOW, 1= MEDIUM, 2=HIGH.
Following code should be able to print the correct information using if and elseif, but for some reason it prints all the rows with "high" as priority, but in the database it has 0 or 1.

```
$pri = $row["prioritet"];
if($pri = 2) {
$pri = "<span class='badge badge-danger'>High</span>";
} elseif($pri = 1) {
$pri = "<span class='badge badge-warning'>Medium</span>";
} elseif($pri = 0) {
$pri = "<span class='badge badge-success'>Low</span>";
}
```

Comment: You are using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: oh lord, i should have known that... that is what happens when i have worked on this project for to long.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if and elseifs need to use the comparison operators ('==' or '===', etc). By using '=', you are inadvertently trying to assign the value 2 to $pri, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `=` instead of `==` which means you are assigning the value of `$pri` to `2` on line 2 instead of comparing them.

Comment: oh lord, i should have known that... that is what happens when i have worked on this project for to long.. thank you!  it worked fine.